# What is the Haskell equivalent of Rust's Read trait?

Tags: haskell

Rust's [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait is an interface that represents a stream of bytes, whether it comes from a socket, a file, from memory, dynamically generated, or something else. It's useful when parsing data to abstract away the source.

What is the equivalent of this in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best fit would probably be a [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), which can do that job and a whole lot more – but is also rather more tricky to wrap your head around.

In many applications, you can also simply use a [lazy `Bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html), or even just a lazy list. Note that thanks to laziness in combination with the garbage collector, such simple “plain data” structures can in Haskell act quite like something that's much more fiddly to do with special e.g. iterators in imperative languages, or that reader trait in Rust.
Unfortunately though, such lazy IO can quite easily lead to nasty surprises (like a file being already closed before you actually have all the data), and it's now generally considered a hack that shouldn't be used in serious code. Conduit, or its more theory-oriented sister library [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), are the “proper” alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you just want to describe parsers for things then emulating Rust's `Read` isn't the only way to do this; `cereal` and `binary` provide binary parsing interfaces that are basically just regular functions taking some chunk of bytes as `ByteString` and then tell you if they can or need to consume more input. You can combine this with [leftroundabout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59815348/938694) if you want to model streams of things you parse from bytes and what not.